# Status Bar is hidden after rotation and navigation

Tags: ios, swift

The status bar defaults to be hidden when rotation is landscape and show up in portrait. However, my status bar will be randomly hidden after rotation and navigation.

I have a collection view showing photos in my album. When clicking on the cell, it segues to another collection view showing specific picture. When I rotate in the `destination` view controller, everything works fine. However, when I navigate back, the status bar will be hidden afterwards.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be helpful, but have you tried setting prefersStatusBarHidden to false?

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return false
}
```

in the controller you navigate back to?

Sorry, I know this should be a comment but I don't have 50 rep

Comment: I like it that you are familiar with StackOverflow's rules. I gave you a little push to help you get that rep, but there's no need to delete this.